# retrieve selected Row data in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF page in which, I have created a html table and displaying the row data using ui:repeat. I have a save button where, when I select a particular row, I want the entire row data to be saved.  When I try to select the particular row, Im unable to get the row data. ui:repeat does not have a binding attribute to bind it to the backing bean dataTable.

Can you please suggest how to acheive the same. Thanks in Advance

Comment: How does the user select the row? By clicking on it, or you are using selectBooleanCheckbox or some other tag for the same?

Comment: Hi Logan, Thanks for the response. Im using the selectBooleanCheckbox tag to select the row in the datatable. Also I have used the html table to create the datatable, since as per my requirement, I need to have a subtable in each row. I was able to acheive this using the html Table option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing the current row as parameter in an action that you must call on `onchange` event of `selectBooleanCheckbox` using `jsf:ajax`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Can you please let me know how to pass the current row data as parameter in the ajax call. Actually, I have not binded my datatable with any backing bean datatable, since Im using general html table (This is because As per my requirement, I need to create nested datatable and it is acheivable only by creating a html table. Your help on this is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How is the table generated? Have you hard coded it, or are using JSTL or some other tag to iterate over the data to be shown in the table?

Comment: Im actually using <ui:repeat> to iterate over the data and display it in the Datatable

Comment: In order to pass the current row value to the function, use the var attribute of the ui:repeat, and pass it as parameter in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to hookup the checkboxes to a bean property:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selection" value="#{listController.checked[item.id]}" />
```

In your bean you would need:

```
private Map<Integer, Boolean> checked = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

public Map<Integer, Boolean> getChecked() {
    return checked;
}
```

Then if you want to know which item(s) were selected you can do:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Boolean> e : checked.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getValue()) {
        // do something with selected row
     }
 }
```